# Cannot publish / deploy a Data Factory from VS2015

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, cortana-intelligence

I am starting to create Azure Data Factories at my company.  Primarily loading data from our on-premise SQL databases to  Azure SQL Data Warehouse.  However, I am only able to publish them from the Microsoft Azure web portal, and not Visual Studio 2015.  When I right-click on the project in Solution Explorer and select the publish button, I am asked to login to MS Visual Studio.  After logging in on the Data Factory Configuration page, I cannot see any existing data factories nor create any new ones.  The Use existing Data Factory Name, Subscription, Resource Group, and Region drop downs are disabled (see screenshot).

[image: Data Factory Configuration]

I am the owner of the Data Factory and have not had any other issues publishing or running pipelines in the data factories I create.  I am the sole developer on the team working with data factories and the person who set me up and configured our Azure services cannot find the problem either.

I imagine it is a configuration issue or something to do with my account. I have re-installed VS2015 Enterprise from scratch to no avail.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have co-admin or admin privileges on atleast one subscription to be able to create or use existing Data Factories. The permissions should be granted using the old management azure portal. If co-admin privileges provided using new portal it wont work.

Thanks
Vijay

Comment: Thank you Vijay.  However I am surprised that such a high privilege is required to publish in Visual Studio.  I would imagine mostly developers or database engineers would be creating data factories, not an administer type person.  Is there a possible fix in the works?

Comment: When updating on VS2015 Update 2, it's not working as well, even I am co-admin on subscription, sad!

Comment: Yes, we are working on relaxing the permissions requirement as we speak. We expect it to be out next month.

Comment: Hi @user6009546.. I'm still experiencing this. I'm listed as contributor in our client's azure sub and can't publish Data Factory via Visual Studio. Did the fix go out?

Answer (score 0):

Open View->Other Windows->Data Factory Task List. There should be log of your operations. It looks like this: 
[Data Factory Task List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTtEZ.png)
If you double click on entry there is more detailed task log